# Form and Sub form save with only one button on MS Access

Tags: save, record, autosave, subform, randomaccessfile

I want to add record with one button on form and sub form. it should remain on current record when cancel or not click button.[Product Detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ9qY.png)
iNVOICE NO

[New Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIsQ2.png)s://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbiL.png

[Invoice Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKEBS.png)

Answer (score 0):

- Go to design tab
- Click and drag the button icon into the main form
- A wizard should pop up, follow the wizard by
- Picking Record operations(to the left),Add new record(to the right)
- Click next(at bottom)
- Check Text
- Click next(at bottom)
- Click finish(at bottom)

The images attached depicts the steps.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Final Output]

Comment: Actually, my question is about one button for both main form and sub form. But when I cancel form it saved record on form.

Comment: You have shared about save button. I want saved button only when click on button then save otherwise remain on current record.

Comment: The images sent handle one button for both main and subform, since it's a parent-child form, the button has to be on the parent/main form. Can you share the code for the cancel form operation?  The button when clicked saves the record and moves to a blank record.

Comment: I m using beforeupdate event on form to stop auto save data in main form and sub form. But when i clicked on sub form to enter data then error occurred. 
Could you share vba code to stop auto save ?